# Convert relative to absolute URLs in Go

Tags: url, go, relative-url

I'm writing a little web crawler, and a lot of the links on sites I'm crawling are relative (so they're `/robots.txt`, for example). How do I convert these relative URLs to absolute URLs (so `/robots.txt` => `http://google.com/robots.txt`)? Does Go have a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the standard library can do this with the `net/url` package. Example (from the standard library):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("../../..//search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    base, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/directory/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(u))
}
```

Notice that you only need to parse the absolute URL once and then you can reuse it over and over.

Comment: Thank you @Not_a_Golfer. Great idea.

Answer (score 6):

On top of @Not_a_Golfer's solution.

You can also use `base` URL's `Parse` method to provide a relative or absolute URL.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    // parse only base url
    base, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/directory/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // and then use it to parse relative URLs
    u, err := base.Parse("../../..//search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(u.String())
}
```

Try it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nuZnRiOrRf6).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `ResolveReference` [method](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.ResolveReference).

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("../../..//search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    base, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/directory/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(u))
}
// gives: http://example.com/search?q=dotnet
```

I use it for my crawler as well and works like a charm!